# What is the operations or treatments we can do on xvalues and not on prvalues and vice versa

Tags: c++11, rvalue

I'm wondering why rvalue expressions are subdivided in two groups (xvalues and prvalues).

Saying differently is there a lot of place where the treatment on rvalues is different according to the fact the expression is either an xvalue or a prvalue? (I think for instance at copy-elision are feature like that). Too much to be enumerated here maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am somewhat unclear on what is asked, but some of the differences between xvalues and prvalues are:

- non-class xvalue can be cv-qualified, prvalue can't be
- class xvalue can be polymorphic, class prvalue is always its most derived type

Comment: Cubbi: Are you agree on the fact than c++ compiler can only realize copy elision with prvalue object type ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 copy/move elision is not specified in terms of expressions. It deals with objects (automatic non-volatile, non-referenced temporary, and the exception object).